# VBA Vlookup/Match Keys return Value

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, formatting, reformat

This may be a very simple fix, so please bare with my "noviceness".  I have a pretty unique form where a user enters a PIN# and the VBA code picks that ID up and changes certain cells based on that ID using a local DB.  The cells are are either populated with data from the DB, formatted differently accordingly, or both.. all based on that PIN#.

I have a piece of code that looks in the DB for the pin, and finds a value that is either N, or Y, and then formats a cell accordingly.  The issue is that I have the code written so that if the value in the DB reads "N" then change the cell value, color, and lock the cell.  If the User types in a PIN# that has a "Y" value in the DB associated, the cells stay the same... then say the user types in a PIN# with a correlated "N" value in the DB , the values change. ALL GOOD, RIGHT?? NO! The problem is that if the user goes back in and types in a different PIN# with a correlated "Y" value in the DB associated, the cells do not go back to the way they were, but stay grey and locked. There has to be a statement for sequential occurrances or something... I am missing something?

```
Sub setChromBox()

 If GetLDBValue(GetHasChrom(Range("START_PIN").value)) = "Y" Then
    Exit Sub
 End If

 If GetLDBValue(GetHasChrom(Range("START_PIN").value)) = "N" Then
    Range("START_GCTR").value = "NO"
    Range("START_GCTR").Interior.ColorIndex = TRColor.Color_Null
    Range("START_GCTR").Locked = True
 Else
    Range("START_MC_LOOKUP").ClearContents
```

Note: GetLDBValue is simply a function to ping the local DB, and GetHasChrom is the query that pings the table in the DB and returns the value of "Y" or "N".  Do I need to add another IF Statement saying something along the lines of If it changes back? Am I way off here? Does code need to be changed elsewhere? Any help is appreciated

Comment: You said it right in the question a PIN# with a "Y" value in the DB stays the same.  The first _If_ statement catches the "Y" and ends the sub-procedure right there, which makes me curious about the _Else Range("START_MC_LOOKUP").ClearContents_ part.  Are Y and N the only 2 values your DB return?  If so, you'd want to remove that first _If_ statement so _Range("START_MC_LOOKUP").ClearContents_ and anything else you want to add in a "Y" scenario.

Comment: This is correct idea as well. Thanks David, if this was an answer i'd rate it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think you're right, you need to change very little in your code though, try this:

```
Sub setChromBox()

 If GetLDBValue(GetHasChrom(Range("START_PIN").value)) = "Y" Then
    Range("START_GCTR").Locked = False
    Range("START_GCTR").value = 'desired text here
    Range("START_GCTR").Interior.ColorIndex = 'Desired Colour here

 Else If GetLDBValue(GetHasChrom(Range("START_PIN").value)) = "N" Then
    Range("START_GCTR").value = "NO"
    Range("START_GCTR").Interior.ColorIndex = TRColor.Color_Null
    Range("START_GCTR").Locked = True
 End If

End Sub
```

If the desired text and colour were what they were before, this is a little trickier. You'll need to store those values somewhere before the 'N' case is run. You could store these either in a cell in a worksheet, or in a public static variable, which will persist between executions of the macro.

Comment: Ok this is going in the right direction. Thanks!  But I am missing the Range("START_MC_LOOKUP").ClearContents, which deletes DB Populated data from the previous pin entered on the sheet.  I think This just goes at the end of the Else if and is the same as previous-- Else .... I tried that and it is working perfectly.  I am super dumb and overthought that completely. Thanks RowanC!